# How to increase compilation and execution priorities of activity on real devices?

Tags: android, android-activity, compilation, execution

I want to know how I can increase the activity priorities to execute its data faster. I have nine view-pagers and all have multiple images in a single activity. When I start this activity it takes between 5-10 seconds. All other activities start with normal animation time, only this activity is taking a long time to display its content on the screen. I am using Bitmap to store the images from the folder of the android device and that's why it takes such a long time.

I want to start this activity with normal time. Is it possible ?

Can I increase the priority of my app's activity to get the results instantly ?

Comment: obviously too much stuff in onCreate and/or on main thread

Comment: @Selvin i am asking that can i increase priorities to execution fast. from manifest or anywhere else.?

Comment: you need to fix your poor code ... there is no such things like *increase priorities to execution fast*

Comment: @Selvin how can i fix.?, I have nine View-pager and all have nine images. it means there are 81 image of 256 * 256  size.

Comment: @Selvin i have set receiver priority to 1000 and its working good. but how to set priority for activity.?

Comment: hehehe did you read the documentation? it is a intent filter priority ... it just change which intent should be used first ...

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any sourcecode, i can only assume whats the reason for your activity to take that much time to be created.

I would say that have to improve you way of loading your images. Try using a library like [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to load and display them. The [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) loads them asynchronously, so your aticvity can be ready while the images themselves load in a background thread.

Comment: *Daily vote limit reached* :( ... but that's the way :)

Comment: @w3hri i am not using any library, Now i am trying your suggestion.

Comment: @w3hri i am getting erro on `.enableloggin();` after added library of your suggestion.